# Cannot use keyboard or mouse after enabling secure boot Windows 11

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios, mouse, windows-11

I cannot use my keyboard or mouse after I have enabled secure boot on my PC. UEFI is enabled and I have installed the factory keys as instructed by my motherboard manufacturer. When I disable secure boot my computer works normally. My mouse and keyboard work in my BIOS and I can press DEL to enter BIOS on start up. I upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 a few months ago which my system is Secure Boot capable. I know that Secure Boot was was enabled at one point when I was on Windows 10 because I was able to use FACEIT AC and Valorant's Vanguard AC with no issue as both requires Secure Boot and TPM to be enabled. When I checked in BIOS, I was on CSM with Secure Boot off. I was able to switch to UEFI with no issues. My drives are all GPT. However, enabling secure boot causes my keyboard and mouse (and all other USB devices) to not work. They are still drawing power as the LEDs on my mouse still works.

Here are the things I tried so far, starting with the obvious ones:

- tried different usb ports + only have mouse and keyboard plugged in
- leaving mouse and keyboard unplugged and plugging it in after reaching lock screen
- uninstalling all drivers and restarting (via device manager and DDU)
- safe mode
- deleting secure keys and reinstalling them in BIOS
- Tried the Legacy USB drivers options on Auto/Enabled/Disabled
- Tried Global C-state control on Auto/Enabled/Disabled
- Configuring Windows Power options to not turn anything off
- reformatting my system drive
- fresh installing different Windows editions (switched from Enterprise to Pro)
- Clearing the CMOS (pulled the battery out for an hour)

I have an MSI B350 GAMING PRO CARBON running Click Bios 5 at the latest version listed on their website. I am on Windows 11 Pro 22H2 with no pending updates.

Comment: If Secure Boot was OFF with Windows 11 running, it must be an Insider version. Windows 11 Production cannot be installed with Secure Boot OFF. Windows Insider is not guaranteed in any way. You can also set the Flag (Registry Key) to install Windows 11 on a non-compliant machine.

Comment: Windows 11 doesn’t support CSM being enabled, Secure Boot is required for most if not all Windows 11 security features, but technically can be disabled. Suspect something is going on just no sure what, suspect it’s a UEFI USB setting, but that doesn’t mean the device supports Windows 11.

Comment: I am fairly sure the registry key that allows this must be set which is what I said.

Comment: What CPU does this system have, MSI B350 GAMING PRO CARBON, is an AM4 motherboard but that isn’t enough information to determine if the CPU is supported by Windows 11

Comment: It appears then the changes that you did make to the Windows 11 requirement settings have caused keyboard and mouse to not work.

Comment: Out of interest, what keyboard/mouse is it? Are any non-microsoft drivers loaded for either of them?

Comment: Its the Steelseries Rival 3 and IKBC Poker 2. I have tried other mouses and keyboards too.

Comment: @Ramhound I have an AMD Ryzen 2700X 4.15GHz processor

Comment: So, you can boot with safe boot off ... run `sigverif`

Comment: The authors system fully supports Windows 11. So I am unsure what changes they could have done to cause this, so I suspect, something yet unidentified is happening that’s unrelated with the system requirements for Windows 11.

Comment: @Bravo I just ran sigverif, It shows everything as signed and verified. And yeah, in my original post I said "When I disable secure boot my computer works normally." Also I am on UEFI but just with the Secure Boot option disabled

Comment: @Bravo I thought that would the best way to signify that Secure Boot was once enabled. I know for sure that Secure Boot was enabled when I was on Windows 10 because FACEIT AC and Valorant's Vanguard requires Secure Boot and TPM to be turned on. Both has worked before on WIndows 10.

Comment: Your statement implies that secure boot must have been on because you upgraded 10 to 11, nothing about this other info you just added

Comment: I will edit the post to reflect this

Comment: do you have another computer you can use to remote desktop into this one (assuming you don't have windows 11 home of course) - that could help you see what's going on in safe boot mode

Comment: you can also try installing amd chipset drivers - https://www.amd.com/en/support - make sure you select the correct ones (though, I think as long as you select AM4, the drivers are all the same, but better safe than sorry)

Comment: I have another computer to use remote desktop. Its on W10 though but I suspect that wont be an issue. Also I have installed the Chipset drivers. My motherboard's website has these drivers in their downloads as well. They did not fix anything when I installed all the drivers but after installing the drivers and running the Chipset driver updater again, it shows the whole list of same drivers to be updated again. Not sure if this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem where **no** USB Device was recognized as soon as I enabled Secure Boot. I just solved it 10 minutes ago and wanted to share :)

To diagnose the issue I enabled Remote Desktop on my machine (System > Remote Desktop > On). This allowed me to use another PC in my network to log in while "Secure Boot" was on even though no input devices worked.
At first my Microsoft Account credentials were not accepted during authentication to the Remote Desktop. I fixed it like this. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/force-refresh-sync-of-microsoft-account-password/d7bddb0d-663f-4775-9593-ce21b17ca800

After connecting to my broken Windows I was able to open the "Device Manager" and found that all of my USB Peripherals had this error:

> Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)

After a bit of googling I found an article that suggests deleting the `UpperFilters` and `LowerFilters` registry keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}`, so I did that. Not really sure what that's for, so do it at your own risk lol.

I also uninstalled all drivers that had the `Code 52` error in the Device Manager.

After these 2 fixes I restarted Windows and **voila!** Working USB Devices. I don't know if uninstalling the Drivers or deleting the filters did the trick.. ‍♂️

Hopefully this helps someone! <3